# reStructuredText link to section with custom text

Tags: restructuredtext

I'm aware of the documentation regarding [implicit hyperlinks](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#implicit-hyperlink-targets) in the reStructuredText manual, but I'm wondering if it is possible to reference a section without having to repeat the full section title. E.g. if I take the example from the documentation,

```
Titles are targets, too 
======================= 
Implict references, like `Titles are targets, too`_.
```

then I'd like to have a way to refer to the section by using a different link name (e.g `` `the target section`_ ``). How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can refer to a section titled `Titles are targets, too` with:

```
`link text <Titles are targets, too_>`_
```

This creates a link whose text is `link text` but points to the section titled `Titles are targets, too`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was missing the `_` inside the `<...>` (this is quite unintuitive...).

Comment: @luator: The reason why one has to do like that is because "Titles are targets, too" is not in fact a hyperlink target, it is a reference to a hyperlink target. `\`Titles are targets, too\`_` works because it expects a hyperlink reference (and is given one), while the angle brackets in: `\`link text <Titles are targets, too>\`_` expect a hyperlink **target**, like HTTP URL. That additional underscore dereferences the reference, so `\`link text <Titles are targets, too_>\`_` becomes: `\`link text <#titles-are-targets-too>\`_`. Yup, the hash target works too.

Comment: "the hash target works, too" ... but only in HTML output (not LaTeX, man page, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can add an alias target in front of the section title:

```
.. _Hyperlinks:

How to define Hyperlinks with reStructuredText
==============================================

This is the section about Hyperlinks_.
```

Especially useful, if the short reference name is required several times in the document. But beware of polluting the "hyperlink namespace".